# Javascript Prototype/Class Function Which Checks Object for Matching Data Returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, logging, match

I'm doing a coding challenge and I'm having difficulty returning anything besides undefined. Instead of true or false from the function defined after

```
Logger.prototype.shouldPrintMessage = function(timestamp, message)
```

I use MD5 Hashing to match if an exact message has been sent prior.

It's probably something obvious but I don't have enough experience with class/constructor functions.

You need to copy and paste the MD5 Hash function to the top of the code for it to work. You can find it in the first comment of this code.

```
// MD5 Hash
// Taken from : http://www.myersdaily.org/joseph/javascript/md5-text.html
// Paste Here

/**
 * Initialize your data structure here.
 */
var Logger = function() {
    this.messageStore = {}
};

/**
 * Returns true if the message should be printed in the given timestamp, otherwise returns false.
        If this method returns false, the message will not be printed.
        The timestamp is in seconds granularity. 
 * @param {number} timestamp 
 * @param {string} message
 * @return {boolean}
 */
Logger.prototype.shouldPrintMessage = function(timestamp, message) {
    let hashedMessage = md5(message);
    if (!(hashedMessage in this.messageStore)){
        this.messageStore[message] = timestamp;
    } else if ((timestamp - this.messageStore.hashedMessage) > 9) {
        return true;
    }
    else if ((timestamp - this.messageStore.hashedMessage) < 10) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return undefined;
    }
};

/** 
 * Your Logger object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * var obj = new Logger()
 * var param_1 = obj.shouldPrintMessage(timestamp,message)
 */

 var obj = new Logger();
 console.log(obj.shouldPrintMessage(1,"foo"));
 console.log(obj.shouldPrintMessage(2,"bar"));
 console.log(obj.shouldPrintMessage(3,"foo"));
 console.log(obj.shouldPrintMessage(8,"bar"));
 console.log(obj.shouldPrintMessage(10,"foo"));
 console.log(obj.shouldPrintMessage(11,"foo"));
```

Comment: your method returns nothing (therefore returns `undefined`) if `hashedMessage` isn't in `this.messageStore`. Which it definitely won't be to started with.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `this.messageStore[hashedMessage] = timestamp;` since that is what you are storing it as, and then anywhere you do `this.messageStore.hashedMessage` you need to do `this.messageStore[hashedMessage']`:

```js
// MD5 Hash
// Taken from : http://www.myersdaily.org/joseph/javascript/md5-text.html
// Paste Here
md5 = window.btoa;
/**
 * Initialize your data structure here.
 */
var Logger = function() {
    this.messageStore = {}
};

/**
 * Returns true if the message should be printed in the given timestamp, otherwise returns false.
        If this method returns false, the message will not be printed.
        The timestamp is in seconds granularity. 
 * @param {number} timestamp 
 * @param {string} message
 * @return {boolean}
 */
Logger.prototype.shouldPrintMessage = function(timestamp, message) {
    let hashedMessage = md5(message);
     if (!(hashedMessage in this.messageStore)){
        this.messageStore[hashedMessage] = timestamp;
        return;
    } else if ((timestamp - this.messageStore[hashedMessage]) > 9) {
        return true;
    }
    else if ((timestamp - this.messageStore[hashedMessage]) < 10) {
        return false;
    }
};

/** 
 * Your Logger object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * var obj = new Logger()
 * var param_1 = obj.shouldPrintMessage(timestamp,message)
 */

 var obj = new Logger();
 console.log(obj.shouldPrintMessage(1,"foo"));
 console.log(obj.shouldPrintMessage(2,"bar"));
 console.log(obj.shouldPrintMessage(3,"foo"));
 console.log(obj.shouldPrintMessage(8,"bar"));
 console.log(obj.shouldPrintMessage(10,"foo"));
 console.log(obj.shouldPrintMessage(11,"foo"));
```

Comment: I'm an idiot. Thanks Dave.

My mind confused messaged and hashed message as the same thing.